# Find-any-action shortcut Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, shortcut

Eclipse has Ctrl+3, Intellij has Ctrl+a for finding just about anything in the whole IDE

- refactorings
- settings
- views, perspectives
- ...

These are magic, sort of uber-shortcuts that makes you effecient in a new IDE in a matter of hours. I can't find the corresponding shortcut in Visual Studio whether with Resharper or not. Is there something of the sort?

Comment: If what you mean is a sort of "Snippet in a box" try Ctrl+K, Ctrl+X.

Comment: I've got a lot of respect for the usability of IntelliJ. Having said that, I find it moronic to use CTRL+a as a shortcut for anything else than "select all". The same goes for CTRL+z, at least in PC world. Don't move my cheese. Ever.

Answer (score 4):

My experience from switching between IntelliJ and VS was that one can't compare individual features and nice-to-haves. In VS, I have specific tasks or aims and then, there are shortcuts for it. Many people customize them and log in to VS using LiveId, so that they have their own stuff.

Resharper has it for **its** settings but you access it from the menu, not globally. In VS generally (depending on you version) there's this "quick find" in the upper right corner <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>.

As for finding classes, files, methods etc. - use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> in R#. Awesome feature.

For defining your own set of shortcuts, you need to use the (somewhat painful) menu under the tools.

Welcome to VS world. We've got it all and you'll love it. But you'll be a bit annoyed when we have it in a less great way than what you're used to.    :)

Answer (score 0):

I use Ctrl+Shift+P !

VSCode 1.76